# Loopback public access by model values

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs

Is there any way to have hook which is checkin that has model attribute **public** and is it true? If it's true, access token is not required? At the moment I have implemented custom endpoints. But is there some other ways?

I have model where is public attribute, like this:

```
{
"name": "Model",
"plural": "model",
"base": "PersistedModel",
"idInjection": false,
"options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
},
"properties": {
    "uuid": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultFn": "uuid",
        "id": true
    },
    "orderNumber":{
        "type":"number"
    },
    "public":{
        "type":"boolean",

    },
    "roles": {
        "type": "object",
        "dataType":"longtext"
    },
    "groupId": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "created": {
        "type": "date",
        "required": true,
        "defaultFn": "now"
    },
    "updated": {
        "type": "date",
        "required": true,
        "defaultFn": "now"
    }
},
"validations": [],
"relations": {

},
"acls": [{
    "accessType": "*",
    "principalType": "ROLE",
    "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
    "permission": "DENY"
}],
"methods": {},
"scope": {

},
"mixins": {
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve that by creating a dynamic role called `accessiblePublic` for example.

Next, in the ACL I would define that this role has access to the endpoint.

Then I would resolve that role dependently on the model that is in the context.

I recommend to read about dynamic roles (and the example there) in the [Docs: Dynamic Roles](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Defining-and-using-roles.html#dynamic-roles)